# Variadic templates transforming between tuples and lists for function calls

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, variadic-functions

The intent is to transform variadic template arguments from pair wise argument to list wise arguments; I mean like:

```
concept NameT = ...
concept ValueT = ...

template<NameT ...ArgName, ValueT ...ArgValue>
Item(ArgName&&... arg_name, ArgValue&&... arg_value) { ... }

std::vector<Item> items;
    
template<typename... Args>
void collect(Args&& ...args) {
   items.emplace_back(arg1_name, arg2_name,..., arg1_value, arg2_value,...):
}

// usage like:
collect(arg1_name, arg1_value, arg2_name, arg2_value, ...);
```

But before I'll go into details, I'll show my testing/concept which is not working as expected, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K3o3vvPf8)

```cpp
template<typename T> concept NameT = std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>;
template<typename T> concept ValueT = std::convertible_to<T, int>;

struct Item {
    template<NameT ...ArgName, ValueT ...ArgValue>
    Item(ArgName&&... arg_name, ArgValue&&... arg_value)
    {
        ((std::cout << std::forward<ArgName>(arg_name) << " : " << std::forward<ArgValue>(arg_value) << '\n'), ...);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto const v1 = Item("arg1", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

results into:

```
candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with ArgName = <>, ArgValue = <const char (&)[5], int>]
```

which I wouldn't really expect (empty ArgName constraint).

So I wrote a small helper to retain the API of name/value arg pairs - of `collect()` and here I am, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bGjx3nrdT)

```cpp
constexpr auto MAX_ARGS = 2;

template<typename T> concept ArgNameT = std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>;
template<typename T> concept ArgValueT = std::convertible_to<T, int>;

struct item_value {
    int value; // becomes variant
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, item_value ival) {
        os << ival.value;
        return os;
    }
};

struct item {
    template<typename... ArgNames, typename... ArgValues>
    item(std::string_view item_name_, ArgNames&& ...arg_names_, ArgValues&& ...arg_values_) 
    : item_name{ item_name_ }
    , arg_names{ std::forward<ArgNames>(arg_names_)...}
    , arg_values{ std::forward<ArgValues>(arg_values_)...}
    {}
    std::string item_name;
    // This memory layout to minimize footprint
    std::array<std::string_view, MAX_ARGS> arg_names;
    std::array<item_value, MAX_ARGS> arg_values;
};

struct logger {
    static logger& instance() {
        static logger static_instance;
        return static_instance;
    };
    template<typename... Args> void add_item(std::string_view name, Args&& ...args);
    template<typename... Args> void do_add_item(std::string_view name, int payload, Args&& ...args);

    using arg_type = struct { std::string_view name; item_value value; };

    auto make_arg_types() { return std::tuple<>(); }

    template<ArgNameT FirstName, ArgValueT FirstValue, typename... Args>
    auto make_arg_types(const FirstName &name, const FirstValue &value, const Args&... args) {
        return std::tuple_cat(
            std::make_tuple(arg_type{name, value}), 
            make_arg_types(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );
    }

    std::vector<item> items;
};

// implementation
template<typename... Args>
void logger::add_item(std::string_view item_name, Args&& ...args) {
    int payload = 69;
    do_add_item(item_name, payload, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template<typename... Args>
void logger::do_add_item(std::string_view item_name, int payload, Args&& ...args) {

    auto arg_types = make_arg_types(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // so far, we have arg name/value tuples ...
    std::apply([](auto&&... arg_type) {
        ((std::cout << arg_type.name << " : " << arg_type.value << '\n'), ...);
    }, arg_types);

    // ... but item's CTor API is different
    //items.emplace_back(item_name, payload, ..., ...); // How to?
}

template<typename... Args>
void collect(std::string_view item_name, Args&& ...args) { // free function
    logger::instance().add_item(item_name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    collect("Superman"); // no arg
    collect("Batman", "is bad"sv, 666); // single arg
    // ... 2 name/value args etc.

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the `collect()`'s API ist solved, but `item` class constructor argument is different (... and rises as new problem), hence I can't emplace them into logger's vector `items`.

How to emplace them?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't simply accept `arg_type`s

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that two parameter packs always end in tears. Concepts won't help.

Comment: As currently defined, I don't think there's any way to call `item` constructor. There's no mechanism to indicate that half the arguments are meant to belong to the first parameter pack and half to the second. Have it take two tuples, or take names and values interleaved and then break into two tuples. The way to separate names from values may [look like this](https://godbolt.org/z/j8arjq85h)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I guess one could do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/aTfrevrYf) to process the first and second half separately.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the wanted target type is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<NameT ...ArgName, ValueT ...ArgValue>
Item(ArgName&&... arg_name, ArgValue&&... arg_value)
{
}
```

this is, in practice, not allowed -- you can't have 2 parameter pack function arguments.

The compiler has no way to know which argument is in which pack, and explicitly refuses to guess.

One approach is to take two tuples:

```
template<NameT ...ArgName, ValueT ...ArgValue>
Item(std::tuple<ArgName...> arg_name, std::tuple<ArgValue...> arg_value)
{
}
```

another is to take a list of pair-like things.

You can also take one huge list, and split it up manually.  You have code that splits it by (a,b,a,b,a,b), but you can do (a,a,a,b,b,b) by halving the list, sticking each half in a `std::forward_as_tuple`, then pairing them up there.

This splits arguments into front and back:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto splitArgsImpl( std::index_sequence<Is...>, auto&&... args ) {
  auto tmpTuple = std::forward_as_tuple( decltype(args)(args)... );
  return std::make_tuple(
    std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<Is>(tmpTuple)... ),
    std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<Is + sizeof...(Is)>(tmpTuple)... )
  );
}
auto splitArgs( auto&&... args ) {
  return splitArgsImpl( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)/2>{}, decltype(args)(args)... );
}
```

then something like:

```
Item makeItem(auto&&...args) {
  auto split = splitArgs(decltype(args)(args)...);
  return std::make_from_tuple<Item>( std::move(split) );
}

template<class...Args> requires (sizeof...(Args) >= 2)
Item( Args&&...args ):Item( makeItem(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) {}

Item( Item&& ) = default;
Item( Item const& ) = default;

template<class Names, class Values>
Item( std::tuple<Names&&...>&& names, std::tuple<Values&&...>&& values ) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: thanks. This split is what I try and failed so far: https://godbolt.org/z/7WoWGhWPj

Comment: How to go with your suggestion in practice by example? Even the last one which sounds promising to me.

Comment: @Olx A sketch of how to do it added.  Probably has typos.